# RadDatetimepicker capture the date

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, telerik, binding

I am working with WPF and C#. I want to fire an event when the user modifies or selects a date on my raddatepicker control. What event handler should I be using for this? I want to be able to convert this captured date to a SQL server 'datetime' variable for use in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectionChanged` is fired when a date is selected or typed + validated.

Comment: What is  DisplayDateChanged in that case?

Comment: That's an event on the RadCalendar control (and System.Windows.Controls.Calendar).  SelectionChanged would seem to be the right event for the RDTP.